# Google Direction API responses waypoint_order with 10 digit numbers

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api, directions

We use the Google Direction API (lib). We call it like this:

```
var directionsService =  new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();
directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {  }
```

Mostly the response is like this:

```
waypoint_order: Array(23)
0: 3
1: 9
...
21: 6
22: 15
length: 23
```

But sometimes we receive this as the response, what results into an error:

```
waypoint_order: Array(23)
0: 4294967295
1: 4294967295
...
22: 4294967295
length: 23
```

Where is this coming from?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?  Your result of 4294967295 is 0xFFFFFFFF (or perhaps -1),  I wouldn't expect that to come from the API.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same issue as of late.  Are you still experiencing it?

Comment: Yes, but we don't know how to reproduce it. It just sometimes comes up.

Comment: Is the rest of the response correct?

Comment: No, they look all the same. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed as of June 20 (evening time in Europe) as reported in Google's Public issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135627404

If you are still encountering the error on your end, you can comment on the issue link above for the engineers to further investigate.